# Preservation of linear separability under linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $a\in\mathbb R^n$ be a given vector. I separate vectors $x\in\mathbb R^n$ into two sets: $S^+ = \{x: a^Tx>0\}$ and $S^- = \{x: a^Tx \le 0\}$.

Now I consider a linear transformation (matrix) $T:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$.

Under what conditions on $a$ and $T$, does there exist a vector $b\in\mathbb R^m$, such that $a^Tx>0$ if and only if $b^TTx>0$ and $a^Tx\le0$ if and only if $b^TTx\le0$?

Comment: What have you tried? Note that $a^Tx = 0$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The best case scenario is that $T(a^T)x = 0$ is also a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^m$. This is surely sufficient, and you can formulate what that means, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @OsamaGhani If $T$ is invertible it's easy. It's the general non-invertible $T$ case that I have difficulty with. Please see my answer.

Comment: What is $v$?...................

Comment: @DanielWainfleet My bad, there is no $v$. Was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Note that in any $\mathbb{R}^m$, $y^Tx = 0$ is a hyperplane if $y \neq 0$. What does this tell you about $T(a)$?

Comment: So it is enough that $a$ is not in the kernel of $T$? In that case, what is $b$? My construction below employs the inverse of $T$ which is not available in general.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question if $T$ is invertible. In that case, the plane $a^Tx=0$ becomes $((T^{-1})^Ta)^T \cdot Tx=0$ after application of $T$. So the vector $b$ is just $b = (T^{-1})^Ta$.

But the conditions for general, non-invertible $T$, elude me.